# Fetch Outlook "Frequently contacted" contact list from API

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi

Is there a way to fetch the "people you frequently contact" list from the outlook contact API?

I cannot find any information in the documentation and figured I'd ask around.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different REST API for people: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/people-rest-operations
It is still in beta, but you can try it.